# PHP get a date one month later

Tags: php

```
<?php

echo "\n";
echo $end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month'));
echo "\n";
$today = date("Y-m-d"); // 2012-01-30
echo $next_month = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$today +1 month"));
echo "\n";
$end_date = mktime(date("H"), date("i"), date("s"), date("n") + 1, date("j"), date("Y"));
echo "\n" . date('Y-m-d',$end_date);
```

http://codepad.org/bHiNFIBR

How can I get the correct date +1 months
I tried these options.
all returned 1 May but I need April 30

Comment: There is no standard way to add 1 month at 31st and to get 30 :)
Perhaps you have to make some IF checks when its 31st to get next month last day.. and when its january 28 + to get last february..

Comment: Check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22755361/php-get-a-date-one-month-later/22755593#22755593

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try something like that..

```
if( date('d') == 31 || (date('m') == 1 && date('d') > 28)){
    $date = strtotime('last day of next month');
} else {
    $date = strtotime('+1 months');
}

echo date('Y-m-d', $date);
```

But just note that when you are 31st March as +1month its correct to target 1st of May not 30th April :)

Comment: January 29th 2016 :P, but other that than, nice one

Comment: Fixed ... 
I missed "of" at the last day string :) without it its generating +1month-1day

Comment: Helped me as well! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest this:

```
$next_month = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 months", strtotime("NOW")));
```

**EDIT**

```
function addMonth($date) {
    $date = new DateTime($date);
    $day = $date->format('j');

    $date->modify("+1 month");
    $next_month_day = $date->format('j');

    if ($day != $next_month_day)
        $date->modify('last day of last month');

    return $date;
}

$next_month = addMonth(time());
echo $next_month->format("Y-m-d");
```

hope this helps :-)

Comment: the second strtotime() will broke everything :) it cant be empty

Comment: it should be time() instead of strtotime()

Comment: still giving out 2014-05-01 instead of 2014-04-30

Comment: @Svetlio @Neo sorry guys i thought default value of strtotime was "NOW" which means today, as `time()` function. By the way i edited it with `strotime("NOW")` which is same as `time()`. Thank you

Comment: @ponciste better use direct time() .. strtotime will be slower :)

Comment: +30 days is giving the right answer i.e. 2014-04-30 but that may break tomorrow... date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+30 days'));

Comment: just figured out what you were looking for. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
echo "\n";
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$next_month = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$today +1 month"));
echo "\n";
echo $next_month_last_day = date("Y-m-d",strtotime('-1 second',strtotime($next_month)));
```

Comment: I liked your suggestion but I will not always get what I need. thank you